# c++ typedef to fix template args

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++03

From c++11, we can do this:

```
template<class A, class B> class C{};
template<class A> using D = C<A, int>;
```

so `D` is `C` with `B=int`.

Is there any way to do this by `typedef` in c++03?

This does not work:

```
template <class A> typedef C<A, int> D;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way that is quite so straight-forward. The only things that can be templates in C++03 are classes and functions. The good thing about classes, is that they themselves can contain a `typedef` as a member.

```
template<class A>
struct D {
  typedef C<A, int> type;
};
```

So now `D<A>::type` stands for `C<A, int>`. This is what is known in template meta-programming as a meta-function. And it's good as you can make it in C++03.

While C++11 introduced alias templates, those require the new alias syntax, with the `using` keyword. An attempt with `typedef`, like you have, isn't valid C++11 either.

Comment: So we can use `D<A>::type d;` to declare `C<A,int> d;`... It is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach similarity on C++03 with inheritance:

```
template<class A> D: public C<A, int> {};
```

Although `D<A>` type is not exact `C<A, int>`, its behavior will be the same.

Comment: While its behaviour will be the same, but it won't be compatible with explicit C<A, int>, which is often an issue. Been there, done that, burnt the tshirt!